# cannot import the module in Python

Tags: python, import

I have the following folder structure.

```
check_site
- test_site
    -- views.py
- app2
- app3
- modules
    -- url.py
    -- usability.py
```

module ulr.py contains one class inside - Url.py

```
class URL:
    ...
```

module usability.py contains one class that inherit URL class

```
from url import URL
class Usability(URL):
    ...
```

And then I have a view.py where I neen to import class Usability

```
from modules.url import URL
from modules.usability import Usability
```

And here is a problem. It gives me an error

```
from url import URL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'url'
```

I've tried to change the import in usability.py to
`from modules.url import URL` but in this case it gives the error in the usability.py

```
Unable to import modules.url
```

I've also tried 
`from .url import URL` and `from check_site.modules.url import URL` But these also don't work

If someone knows how to fix it, please help

Comment: what is the location your current script running? output of `sys.path`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem lies here because by default Python searches for the file in the current directory but the file u want to import is not in the same directory as your program.
You should try `sys.path`

```
# some_file.py
import sys
# insert at 1, 0 is the script path (or '' in REPL)
sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/application/app/folder')

import file
```

This should work in most cases.